# camera calibration quality

Tags: calibration, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all!
I am using [camera calibration node](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/MonocularCalibration) for monocular camera. Is there any criterion that says how well the camera was calibrated?
And the second question is: should I pass rectified image to some algorithm after calibration or it will be redundant?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256427/camera-calibration-quality/) by [psi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27476/psi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the official ROS documentation available [here](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration#Camera_Check)  you can check your calibration using *cameracheck.py*  the following way:

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracheck.py --size 8x6 monocular:=/forearm image:=image_rect
```

Remember that you need to click **COMMIT** after your calibration is done for the calibration parameters to be uploaded to the camera driver.

---

Originally posted by [Higarian](https://answers.ros.org/users/31461/higarian/) with karma: 51 on 2017-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2